# EAR not working in Weblogic 10.3.6

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, weblogic, thymeleaf, ear

I'm using Eclipse and when I run the Spring MVC project under Pivotal tc (aka Tomcat), I have an image that is shown correctly (and I can reach its URL), but when I run under Weblogic 10.3.6 the EAR project (which load the Spring MVC project) the image is not showed, and when I try to load directly the image URL (on browser "open in a new window"), I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()I
    at org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletWebRequest.checkNotModified(ServletWebRequest.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:241)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:442)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

The image is under: /resources/images/
I load it through:

```
<img th:src="@{/resources/images/0-logo.gif}" />
```

And in the xml I have:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

Why is the image showed only when I run on tomcat my project Foo, and not when I run under Weblogic the FooEAR? What can I do? Do I need any additional configuration?

### **Solution:**

Downgrading from spring 4.2.0.RELEASE to 3.1.4.RELEASE and thymeleaf from 2.1.3.RELEASE to 2.1.2.RELEASE solved my problem. Read the answer for more details.

Comment: What version of Weblogic are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HttpServletResponse#getStatus](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getStatus%28%29) is only added in Servlet 3.0. The issue is caused by an older Servlet implementation supplied by your application server. Check the version of Weblogic then see whether it implements Servlet 3.

Update : According to the information provided, the version of Weblogic you are using is 10.3.6. Looking at this [Servlet version support table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_WebLogic_Server#Standards_support_by_version), you should atleast use Weblogic 12c in order to work with Servlet 3.

Comment: There is no way to force a non Servlet 3 compliant app server to use Servlet 3. You have to remove your application code's dependencies to Servlet 3.

Comment: Mhh thanks, and where can I find this dependencies? Project settings? Some xml? On Java code (maybe because I used annotation?)?

Comment: Identify which class under which artifact is throwing the exception. Once identified, google for the version of the arifact that is designed to work on Servlet 2.5.

Comment: I added the entire stacktrace. If I call the webpage, It's correctly loaded (except the image). I get the error only when on the image I select from the browser "open in a new window".

Comment: I don't know why, but downgrading from spring 4.2.0.RELEASE to 3.1.4.RELEASE and thymeleaf from 2.1.3.RELEASE to 2.1.2.RELEASE solved my problem.
Should be linked to your answer?

Comment: Yes it is. Spring MVC 3.2 is the first version to use Servlet 3. So downgrading to version before that means downgrading to Servlet 2.5.

Comment: Is it possible using spring 4.2 with servlet 2.5?

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-4.0.html) says it is possible, but Servlet 3 is strongly recommended. If u insist on using Spring 4 with Servlet 2.5 you have to be careful not to hit on a feature that particularly uses Servlet 3. It will be very difficult. I recommend you to just downgrade your Spring version to < 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the problem is with the context root mapping.

Try to add a WebLogic specific deployment descriptor and add the context-root stance.

Try checking the [WebLogic deployment descriptor docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/web.1111/e13712/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP623) for more information on how to do that.